# MDbootstrap materialSelect is not a function Rails and Webpacker app

Tags: mdbootstrap

Im trying to figure out why the function `materialSelect()` is doesn't exist in the app context.

The MDboostrap select field is created correct with behaviour and style but I am trying to destroy and re-initialize using `materialSelect()` such as:

```
 const $select = $('.mdb-select');
 $select.materialSelect({destroy: true});   
 $select.materialSelect();
```

I get the follow error:

```
materialSelect is not a function
```

This app uses Rails 6/Webpacker. I think there is a file missing here since this app was created without the min.js file, instead each mdbootrap dependency was downloaded and added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not working is because of the MDBoostrap version. This project uses 2.2.1 and materialSelect() doesn't exist under this version. I was able to get it working on latest version 4.20.0